# Replace and preview multiple image upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, file-upload

I have images being dynamically shown with this code

```
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT post_gallery_img FROM posts WHERE post_id = $get_post_id";
        $select_gallery_imgs = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_gallery_imgs)) {
            $post_gallery_img = $row['post_gallery_img'];

            $post_gallery_img = explode(',', $row['post_gallery_img']);

            foreach($post_gallery_img as $out) {
                echo '<img class="imgFile" id="editPostGalleryImgs" src="../userImages/' . $out . '" alt="Post Image">';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

And the result is this

[image: 3 dynamic images]

Now I am trying to let the user upload multiple new images but I want them to be able to preview the new images in place of the dynamic ones.

I have this code for the multiple preview

```
<input id="galleryImgs" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]"><button style="display: none;" onclick="reset2($('#galleryImgs'));event.preventDefault()"></button>
<div class="gallery"></div>

<script>
 $(function() {
  // Multiple images preview in browser
  var imagesPreview = function(input, editPostGalleryImgs) {

    if (input.files) {
        var filesAmount = input.files.length;

        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(event) {
                $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(editPostGalleryImgs);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        }
    }

  };

  $('#galleryImgs').on('change', function() {
      imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
  });

});
</script>
```

Which brings back this 
[image: dynamic images]

The problems is, I want the preview images to replace the dynamic images instead of them being displayed on top.

Comment: Target an existing image and use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) ?

Comment: just use .`.empty()` to get rid of the existing html inside an element and then replace it .

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette playing around but no luck, do you have an example?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Got it! Used replaceWith() thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Got my desired result by using replaceWith()

Changed This

```
imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
```

To This

```
$(".imgFile").replaceWith(imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery'));
```

And it works perfect now!